# Attempting to add class with delay whilst in an jquery each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get a few elements to fade in one at a time with Javascript/jQuery and I simply can't get anything working.

I've tried every 'solution' on StackOverflow there is to this problem, and nothing works. Either 1) The elements I'm trying to animate all animate at once, 2) nothing is animated at all, or 3) I get a Javascript error. Take a look at my current code:

```
        $('.tagline').each(function(i, e) {

                setTimeout(function(i, e) {
                    e.addClass('animated');
                }, 500 * i);
        });
```

The above code tells me `e is undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setTimeout` callback doesn't accept any parameters, you are overriding the `i` and  `e` parameters of the each callback with `undefined` values:

```
$('.tagline').each(function(i, e) {
     setTimeout(function() {
         $(e).addClass('animated');
     }, 500 * i);
});
```

Comment: +1 from me. I was writing the exact same block of code

Answer (score 1):

If you fancy having control over your own fader you could always take the data approach. If you wanted something to fall back on you could always add a condition if null. http://jsfiddle.net/rg45yduh/3/

```
$(function(){
    $('.tagline').each(function(){
       delay=$(this).data('time-delay');
       fadeout= $(this).data('fade-out');              
       $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(fadeout);
    })
})
```

Comment: Your more than welcome. I use this approach a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/rg45yduh/

```
$('.tagline').each(function (i) {
    $(this).delay((i++) * 500).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Or to add a class

```
$('.tagline').each(function (i) {
    $(this).delay((i++) * 500).addClass('animated');
});
```